# Tmux split window command not working after brew upgrade

Tags: tmux

I wanted to run 'brew update' but run 'brew upgrade'.

After that, my tmux stop working on some functionalities.

For example, I cannot split windows. I have already tried using shortcut (`Prefix-%`), terminal command (`tmux split-window`), or tmux command (`Prefix-:split-window`). Sometimes the terminal divides the window for a fraction of time and then the new pane fades out. Sometimes nothing happens.

If tmux is detached, I can attach with `tmux attach` but some other commands are not working. For example, if I run `tmux new-session -As "foo"`, it returns the string `[exit]` and if I inspect the return (`echo $?`), it returns 0.

I have already tried to run tmux without any configuration in case my tmux.conf have some problems. But when I run `tmux -f /dev/null`, it returns the string `[exit]` and if I inspect the return (`echo $?`), it returns 0.

The problem is that I am not sure if the problem is with tmux itself (it was upgraded to 3.2a - and I did not remember which version it was before) or if the problem is with another program or with the fact I am running with Mac M1 processor, that causes me problems in a bunch of situations.

I have already tried to downgrade tmux but there are not many materials on how to do that I the ones that I tried did not work. So I give up, especially because I was not sure if this would solve the problem.

In summary, I need some help at least to know how to best debug the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and could fix it by just restarting my tmux session. Dettaching and reattaching is not enough.